# jquery slide left and right to div next or back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for very simple function to slide right or left for next or back div. 
Actually I want to build a page with out any scroll on x,y.

Div1 one have a button. When press that button it should show div2 on page with slide in effect. I do not want scroll please. (div1 should hide)

Then div2 have button to show div3 and div3 have button to show div5 and back to div1.
Please help me with this.
Here i am adding example code of html
Thank you

```
<div class="div1" id="div1">
    <button class="btn">Slide right to div 2</button>
</div>

<div class="div2" id="div2">
    <button class="btn">Slide right to div 3</button>
</div>

<div class="div3" id="div3">
    <button class="btn">Slide left to div 1</button>
    <button class="btn">Slide right to div 5</button>
</div>

<div class="div4" id="div5">
    <button class="btn">Slide right to div 3</button>
    <button class="btn">Slide right to div 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: why is `div4` skipped in the IDs ? also why don't you use BootStrap Carousel / Owl carousel / any other slider like Swiper JS

Comment: Can add div4. no issue with this. Carousel not work same as I am looking for. Like if I want to travel from div5 to div1 it would travel through all other div in between I just want to go to div1 directly

Comment: Right, but bootstrap [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) would make only one slide to go to the target slide, check it out

Comment: try using jQuery.DIYslider ex: http://pioul.fr/jquery-diyslider